Hibernate OnetoOne Mapping Join Issue
I have created two entities with unidirectional mapping
class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    @Column(name = "user_id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String userId;

    @Column("email")
    private String email;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id",insertable=false, updatable=false)
    private UserAccountStatus accountStatus;
}

public class UserAccountStatus {

    @Id
    private String userId;
    private String status;
}

I am making following 2 queries
 @EntityGraph(attributePaths = {"accountStatus"})
    Optional<UserEntity> findByEmail(String email);     ---> query 1

    @EntityGraph(attributePaths = {"accountStatus"})
            @Query("SELECT u FROM UserEntity u WHERE u.kycVerified = true and u.accountStatus.status = 'ACTIVE'") ---> query2 

    Slice<UserEntity> findAllVerifiedAndActiveUsers(Pageable pageable);

for query 1 hibernate created  with LEFT JOIN
``` select
        *
    from
        user_entity ue1_0 
    left join
        cs_customer_status as1_0 
            on as1_0.user_id=ue1_0.user_id 
    where
        ue1_0.email=? ```

for query 2  hibernate created below query with just JOIN
select
        *
        from
        user_entity ue1_0 
    join
        cs_customer_status as1_0 
            on as1_0.user_id=ue1_0.user_id 
    where
        ue1_0.kyc_verified=1 
        and as1_0.status='ACTIVE' 
    limit
        ?, ?

how to force hibernate to generate left join instead of just join in query 2 so i can get users who does not have accountStatus as null
I am expecting hibernate to generate left join in both queries

Your 2nd query working as expected
For query 1 you should use HQL
@EntityGraph(attributePaths = {"accountStatus"})
@Query("SELECT u FROM User u WHERE u.kycVerified = true and u.email = :email and u.accountStatus.status = 'ACTIVE'")
Optional<User> findByEmail(@Param("email") String email);

